# How get key from query Firebase in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get the key where `UID` be equal to: `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`, because I can update this information when the user enters new data.

How to update the information? I use `orderByChild` and equal and set, but don't work.

[image]

My code:

```
updateUserInformation() {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/');
  ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      if (child.val().UID == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
        this.profileData = [{
          name: child.val().name,
          lastname: child.val().lastname,
          phone: child.val().phone,
          direction: child.val().direction,
          followQuantity: child.val().followQuantity,
          points: child.val().points,
          sex: child.val().sex,
        }];
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have unique `UID` fields in your Realtime Database, this is what you can do:

```
updateUserInformation() {
  const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild('UID').equalTo(uid);
  ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    const updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      const userKey = child.key;
      const userObject = child.val();
      updates[`${userKey}/fieldWhichYouWantToUpdate`] = `Field Value you want it to set to`;
      firebase.database().ref('/users/').update(updates);
    });
  })
}
```

I haven't tested this out but I think this should work.

Comment: Sorry, I want update the information in firebase database, this.profileData is wrong, I don't know if you understand me.

Comment: @JuanmaPerez, please try the updated answer. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: It would be way easier if you used **[`@angular/fire`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)** BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with Firestore and ES6 Promises. If you consider switching to Firestore, the query would look like this:

```
    updateUserData = (user) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebaseService.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.id)
            .update({
                name: user.name,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                ...
                })
            .then(() => {
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @SiddAjmera is correct. It also shows a disadvantage of your current data model: there may be multiple nodes that have the correct UID. While you application may not allow this, your data model does, and you can't enforce a unique value of the UID through security rules.

Whenever you're storing items that have a natural identifier, consider storing those items using that natural ID as their key. In the case of users that means that you should strongly consider storing the users in their UID.

```
users: {
  "BD21...Wv33": {
    "email": "test2@test.com",
    ...
  }
}
```

This this structure:

- You are guaranteed that each user's UID can occur only once, since keys are by definition unique in a parent node.
- You can simply look up a user by their UID with:

  ```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(uid);
  ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
    snapshot.ref.child("fieldWhichYouWantToUpdate"].set("Field Value you want it to set to");
  })
  ```